# gmaps.js trigger infoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps.js

I'm having a bit of difficulty figuring out how to trigger a specified infoWindow using gmaps.js

My map is initialized as follows:

```
map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map-canvas'
});
renderMarkers();
```

My renderMarkers function basically executes an AJAX call to a PHP script which queries the database and returns a result set, and returns a series of addMarker calls like this:

```
LOOP THROUGH RESULT SET {

    map.addMarker({
        lat: marker.SiteLatitude, 
        lng: marker.SiteLongitude,
        infoWindow: {
           content: marker.contentHTML,
           closeclick: function(e) {
               $("#customer-details-container").hide();
           }
       },
       icon: marker.iconPath,
       id: marker.MyID
   })

}
```

I refresh/re-render the markers as the client triggers updates to the underlying database by using map.removeMarkers() and then triggering my renderMarkers() function. When the markers get redrawn on the map, if the user had an infoWindow open I want to trigger it to open.

I'm not sure how to trigger an infoWindow based on a specific ID. As an example, lets just say a marker was setup like so:

```
    map.addMarker({
        lat: 102.325 
        lng: -67.524,
        infoWindow: {
           content: "<div>test!</div>"
           closeclick: function(e) {
               $("#customer-details-container").hide();
           }
       },
       icon: "image/marker.png",
       id: 1234
   })
```

Am I correct in saying that I should be able to target it using that ID=1234? eg:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(markers[1234], 'click');
```

??

I'm not sure of the specific syntax to execute this using gmaps.js

ANY help greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Am I correct in saying that I should be able to target it using that ID=1234?*

I don't think so. The documentation is very incomplete and inside the gmaps.js I can't find anything with a functionality to access a marker by a property.

But you may extend the prototype:

```
GMaps.prototype.markerById=function(id){
  for(var m=0;m<this.markers.length;++m){
    if(this.markers[m].get('id')===id){
      return this.markers[m];
    }
  }
  return new google.maps.Marker();
}
```

usage:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map.markerById(12345), 'click');
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Every marker added to the Gmaps.map intance has it's own InfoWindow stored into the markers object. We need the Array index key to that specific marker. Adress by the index key the right InfoWinow o be opened. You can open the GMaps.js specific marker by doing following:

```
(map.markers[index].infoWindow).open(map.map,map.markers[index]);
```

Replace [index] by the index of the marker you want the InfoWindow to open.

Comment: Works well but could you also tell how to close all the other infowidow except for the index?

Comment: Hi @AmitSingh, to close all infowindows you can loop all the infoWindows and call the 'close()' function. You can always add a custom check on ex. the index ...